# Setting default page in PowerBI Embedded

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have 5 pages in my report and I am using the same report in 2 different applications. Is it possible to set default page as per application i.e.; Application 1 should have Page 1 as default page where as Application 2 should have Page 5 as default page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a new query string parameter you can pass call `pageName=<ReportSectionName>`

The report section name is a little confusing it's not the name of the page you see in the UI. Instead it's at the end of the URL in the browser's address bar.

So log in to www.powerbi.com and upload your report to see what the section names are.  Then you can use them in your Power BI Embedded environment.

You can see the actual `pageName` value for each report-page through the share-URL balloon:

[image]